# Stop body scrolling on iOS when menu open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to stop the body scrolling underneath the menu I'm opening using javascript.

```
<script>
  $('.mobile-menu-link').click(function(){
      $('body').toggleClass("no-scroll");
  });
</script>
```

Currently I'm toggling a class on the body which just adds the property 'overflow:hidden' but this stops it scrolling on the desktop but seems to fail on mobile, is there any javascript or CSS I'm missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there's lots of ways to do it, i think this will do the job

```
body.no-scroll{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
}
```